# how to remove the [ ] symbol

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list with dictionary data type:

```
venueList = [{'VIP Room':10,'Executive Room':30,'Pool Site':50}]
```

And I have this program:

```
print([d['VIP Room'] for d in venueList])
```

where it prints:

```
[10]
```

how to remove the [] symbol and is there a much simpler ways to print it.Thanks

Comment: `print(*[d['VIP Room'] for d in venueList])` will take the list you made and pass all of its elements (just one using your sample data) as individual arguments to `print`

Comment: `print([d['VIP Room'] for d in venueList][0])`

Comment: If the dict is the first element of `venueList`, you can do `venueDict = venueList[0]` to get the dict.

Comment: I made an edit with the explain, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have only 1 element(dict) in the list

```
venueList[0]['VIP Room']
#Output:
#10
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now your list only has one element (it's a **singleton list**), so it might make sense to print just the lone element. However, consider what you want for when there is more than just one element.

```
k = [d['VIP Room'] for d in venueList]
```

First we start with that.

If you want to output them as a list, just `print(k)`. However, if you want the `[]` gone and using commas for separation, you can do `print(", ".join(str(e) for e in k))`. If you want to print them with spaces as separation, you can do `print(*k)`, which equates to calling `print(k[0], k[1], ..., k[-1])`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for d in venueList:
    print(d['VIP Room'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have a list with only one element, and that element is a dict, you just need to unwrap the value, take the list away, and print the value assoc to the key you want:

```
venueList = [{'VIP Room':10,'Executive Room':30,'Pool Site':50}]

print(venueList.pop()['VIP Room'])
```

You can check it here: https://repl.it/NW0S/1

Comment: No no no no way... just tell me now why the down vote... imposible.. it does the job perfectly

Comment: There's no reason for this to be a list comprehension and not a for loop.  You're just building a list of `None`s that you do nothing with

Comment: @PatrickHaugh ok ok... you got a point, and it's a good one, I made an edit because you are right, and I was wrong